# What is an [algorithm], and how should it be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the main site, we have the tag [algorithm](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) and I'm a bit confused about the purpose of this tag.

On one hand, while currently 25 questions have this tag ([rank #5](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/tags)), I fail to see what they have in common with respect to *algorithms*. On the other hand, when looking over the front page, I also fail to find questions, which are not somehow about *algorithms*.

So, **what is the purpose of this tag?** (Does it have a purpose?) Can someone please explain this, maybe also with examples of questions that should and should not have this tag and why? Or should we remove this tag?